# What is the default prototype for a new instance?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the following behavior:

```
var Foo = function () {};
var Bar = function () {};
Foo.prototype = Bar;
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.prototype === Bar.prototype); // true, but why?
```

I can't find anything in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) regarding the default value of the `prototype` property on an object created using a constructor. (I did find [this part of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2) which mentions that, for functions, the `prototype` property defaults to `new Object()`, but no mention of objects created using constructors.)

So, my question is really two-fold:

What is the default value of the `prototype` property on an object created using a constructor? (It seems like it is the `prototype` property of the `prototype` property of the constructor; e.g. `Foo.prototype.prototype`)

Where does it explain this behavior in the spec?

Comment: you set "Foo.prototype = Bar", why would it be anything else?

Comment: @dandavis: OPs point is `Bar = Foo.prototype` so s/he is visualizing `Foo.prototype == (Foo.prototype).prototype`.

Comment: ahh. the default value of the prototype property on an object created using a constructor is a blank object derived from that constructor. ex: new String() will give you an object with few own methods, but all the inherited String.prototype methods like slice() and bold(). if you compare inst.bold to String.prototype.bold, they should be the same.

Comment: @dandavis, I'm not sure we're on the same page. Open a console and type `var x = new String(); console.log(x.prototype);` and you'll see it's actually `undefined`. I believe you're speaking of the prototype of the object, not the `prototype` property on the object. (In Chrome, this is the `__proto__` property.)

Comment: i never mentioned instance .prototype, i said (x.bold==String.prototype.bold), but know that x.__proto__ == x.constructor.prototype if that helps.

Comment: I just want to point out (because you didn't make it explicit in your question) that `Foo.prototype = Bar;` is *totally the wrong way* to do prototype chaining. It should be `Foo.prototype = new Bar;` or `Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype);`. Maybe you already knew this?

Comment: Thanks, @apsillers. Yes, I'm aware of this. I was just trying to understand everything around prototype in JavaScript, and came across this strange behavior. I would never actually write code like that of the post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the default value of the `prototype` property on an object created using a constructor?

`undefined`, unless what you're constructing is a function. The `prototype` property belongs on functions. If an instance object does not have a function object in its prortype chain (i.e., `instanceObj instanceof Function` is `false`), the instance generally will not have a `prototype` property.

The reason that functions have a `prototype` property because any function might someday be used as a constructor. A constructor's `prototype` property determines the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of its constructed instances.

> (It seems like it is the `prototype` property of the `prototype` property of the constructor; e.g. `Foo.prototype.prototype`)

You only see with behavior because you've assigned `Foo.prototype` *to the function `Bar`*. Thus, when you try to get `foo.prototype`, the interpreter looks up `foo`'s prototype chain and finds the `prototype` property on the function `Bar`.

In particular, `foo.prototype === Bar.prototype` is true because:

1. To get `foo.prototype`, we first try to get `prototype` off of `foo`.
2. `foo` has no `prototype` property.
3. Look up the prototype chain: `foo`'s `[[Prototype]]` was set to `Foo.prototype` when `foo` was constructed. (Remember, `Foo.prototype` is the function `Bar`.)
4. Look for `prototype` on `Bar`.
5. Success! `Bar.prototype` is defined. Use that for `foo.prototype`.
6. Unsurprisingly, `Bar.prototype` is equal to `Bar.prototype`.

> Where does it explain this behavior in the spec?

- [15.3.5.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.2) explains that the `prototype` property is used as the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of its constructed objects.
- [13.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) (steps 5 - 7) spells out the exact procedure described in 15.3.5.2, above.
- [8.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) describes general prototype-based inheritance  (i.e., if an object doesn't have a property, look at its `[[Prototype]]`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant explanation. I now feel like an idiot for not checking `foo.hasOwnProperty("prototype")` and seeing that it was `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype of a constructed object is the object referenced by the constructor function's `.prototype` property.

So because `foo.__proto__ === Bar`, then obviously `foo.__proto__.prototype = Bar.prototype`.

The `foo` object does not have `.prototype` property, it is looked and found in `foo.__proto__` because the object's prototype is a function object which have a prototype property, this is what you missed.

Comment: If the prototype of a constructed object is the object referenced by the constructor function's `.prototype` property, then it all makes sense. Is this explicitly detailed in the specs?

Comment: That's it. And the answer to the question *What is the default value of the prototype property on an object created using a constructor?* is, it's `undefined`.